# How can I autoresize the height of UICollectionViewCell?

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell

I have an UICollectionView with the next custom cell:

[image]

Now, I want to resize my UICollectionViewCell height according to the height of UITableView at the bottom

So, the height of my cell can be 500, 400, 800, etc.

I work over it almost a week and cannot solve this problem. Can anyone help me with it?

I've tried 2 methods:

With:

```
func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> CGSize {
```

and with the:

```
(collectionView.collectionViewLayout as! UICollectionViewFlowLayout).itemSize = CGSizeMake(100, 100)
```

but no one works. Can anyone help me with it, please?

Comment: Nevertheless, `sizeForItemAtIndexPath` is correct. You don't show your actual code, so you must be doing it wrong. But no one can help you because you have concealed what you are doing!

Comment: What you want to see? I'll show it. I do not know what part exactly you want to see, and my code is long. So that's why I did not paste here my code. Can you help me please?

Comment: @matt please, look at it: http://pastebin.com/hFNvJLXk . I do not know what to write in `sizeForItemAtIndex` to make it dynamic

Answer (score 0):

```
sizeForItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> CGSize {
   let height = yourTableView.view.frame.height
   let percentRatio = 0.2 
   return CGSize(width: collectionView.cellForItemAtIndexPath(indexPath)?.frame.width, height: height * percentRatio)
}
```

Put this in the ViewController that serves as the Data Source and Delegate of your collectionview. The percent ratio is the percent of the height of the table. You can change it to whatever you like. Hope it helps!

Comment: but my tableview size is dynamic. It can be 100, 500, 200, etc. That's why I have problems =/